# Mounting WebDAV drive in Windows Server 2012

Tags: webdav, windows-server, network-drive, net-use

I having problems mounting a webdav drive via explorer or cmd with the following command:

```
net use z: "https://.." /user:username password

System error 67 has occured.
The network name cannot be found.
```

Everything working fine on my other machines. 
Thought I had to install the "Desktop Experience" Feature but cant find it in Server Manager / Add Features. I`ve already added the "Media Foundation" Feature and the "WebDAV Publishing" is even installed with IIS. I cant find the WebClient Service in services.msc.

Any suggestions, how enable client side webdav support?

Answer (score 10):

Just solved this on a 2012 R2 for connecting a WebDAV drive from OwnCloud 7 server via HTTPS (think it's same on 2012)

1. **Install Desktop Experience**

server manager > Add Features > User Interfaces and Infrastructure > Desktop Experience

2. **Start and set to Automatic WebClient Service**

services > WebClient > Properties > Set from Manual to Automatic then start it

3. **Enable BasicAuthLevel in regedit**

open regedit.exe and go to this key
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters

set the DWORD value "BasicAuthLevel" to "1"

4. **reboot**
5. **connect to your WebDAV**

net use z: "https://.." /user:username password

Comment: you can use also the Windows Explorer "Map Network Drive" feature with same results

Comment: for some reason this worked on one machine, the other one gives me SystemError 53.... Windows ...

Comment: this works, thank you! but the registry hack is not necessary, at least on windows server 2012 R2, if the webdav server supports digest authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution to this problem for Windows Server 2016:

1. Install WebDAV-Redirector component via PowerShell

   ```
   Install-WindowsFeature WebDAV-Redirector –Restart
   ```
2. Verify that WebDAV-Redirector is installed properly

   ```
   Get-WindowsFeature WebDAV-Redirector | Format-Table –Autosize
   ```
3. WebClient service should appear in your system. By default it is started in Manual mode, just set it to Automatic and that's it.
4. Reboot

All credits for this answers goes to [IT Bros](https://theitbros.com/installing-webdav-client-windows-server-2016/).

Answer (score 0):

For a *Server 2012R2 Essentials*, penzoiders' answer does not work because Essentials does not have the server manager and I couldn't find a way to install the Desktop Experience through Dashboard.

However, the installation via PowerShell described in the IT Bros link in Suncatcher's answer also works on Server 2012R2 Essentials:

```
Install-WindowsFeature Desktop-Experience
```

Right after the reboot I was finally able to mount Magentacloud via WebDAV.